# laravel homestead installation

Tags: git, bash, laravel-4

Im having trouble about ther installation of laravel on windows.
when typing the following command in git bash

`$vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

this message will appear next:

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via vagrant login. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found
```

please help. how to fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

on investigation I found curl located in C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin complained of

The program can't start because MSVCP100.dll is missing from computer.

The dll is provided by [MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributables](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555) something I had on my old install for another program. Installing it makes vagrant work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you create account in [VagnantCloud](https://vagrantcloud.com/) service?!
are you logged in this service from your console with first vagrant share command?!

Good Job!